# How to change background Color on div with active class in react js?

Tags: css, reactjs

I use BrowserRouter and Navlink in React. After clicking on a given link, when it is selected, it has the active class from react-router-dom. I would like to change the back ground color on the all div (menu-box), not only around the text.

```
<div className="container-menu">
          <div className="menu">
            <ul className="menu-list">
              <div className="menu-box" >
                <li className="menu-item">
                                  <NavLink className="menu-link " to="/customers" >
                    Customers
                  </NavLink>
                </li>
              </div>
              <div className="menu-box">
                <li className="menu-item">
                  <NavLink className="menu-link" to="/schedule">
                    Schedule
                  </NavLink>
                </li>
              </div>
              <div className="menu-box">     
              <li className="menu-item">
                <NavLink className="menu-link" to="/invoices">
                  Invoices
                </NavLink>
              </li>
              </div>
              <div className="menu-box">
              <li className="menu-item">
                <NavLink className="menu-link" to="/reports">
                  Reports
                </NavLink>
              </li>
              </div>
              <div className="menu-box">
              <li className="menu-item">
                <NavLink className="menu-link" to="/settings">
                  Settings
                </NavLink>
              </li>
              </div>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
```

```
.menu {
  background-color: #2d4a59;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  .menu-item {
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(242, 247, 250, 0.1);
    padding: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;

    .menu-link {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: $menu-text;
      display: block;
      height: 100%;
    }
  }
  .active {
    background-color: $header-backGround;
  }

   .menu-box:hover {
    background-color: $menu-hover;
  }
}
```

I would like to change the back ground color on the all div, not only around the text.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has `.menu-link:has(.active)`

Comment: Just to say, wrap your `li` elements in `div` is a mistake, don't break html standards, you don't need the `div` elements here.

Comment: I'm aware of this, I did it to have a hover over the entire div.